# AWS MediaConvert - Stitch Portrait and Landscape videos

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I'm working on a side project using AWS MediaConvert to stitch together multiple video files.

MediaConvert now supports rotating video inputs, so if I have a video that was shot in portrait - usually from a cell phone - I can rotate it 90 degrees for correct display.

The problem is that if my first video input is portrait, and I configure it to rotate, either 90 degrees or "automatic", all subsequent video inputs are rotated as well regardless of any rotation setting I apply.

Has anyone encountered this issue to know of a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Media Convert. It has been fixed as of summer 2019.